# How to update rows when WHERE value is a sub query with more than 1 row of results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to run this SQL:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
   SET meta_value = 1.00 
 WHERE meta_key = '_test' 
   AND post_id = (SELECT post_id 
                    FROM wp_postmeta 
                   WHERE meta_value = 8032)
```

I was hoping it would set `meta_value` to `1.00` where the `meta_key` is `_test` and `post_id` is any of the returned `post_id` from the sub query: `SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = 8032`

Upon simulating this query in phpMyAdmin it says that **the sub query has more than 1 result**, therefore how can I make this work?

Maybe it's not really something to do in SQL, I guess I could pull the `post_id` sub query results into PHP then loop through them and then do the original SQL..?

Comment: Replace `=` with `IN`

Comment: what is the need of subquery here as you are fetching and updating data from the same table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `=` with `IN`:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = 1.00 
WHERE 
    meta_key = '_test' 
    AND post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = 8032)
```

But as table is the same why not just:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = 1.00 
WHERE 
    meta_key = '_test' 
    AND meta_value = 8032
```

Error

> Table 'wp_postmeta' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

can be fixed as

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = 1.00 
WHERE 
    meta_key = '_test' 
    AND post_id IN (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = 8032
        ) t
    )
```

Comment: because post_id might refer to more than one meta_value

Comment: @Strawberry even so the 'post_id might refer to more than one meta_value' the second query would do the job

Comment: This answer = to IN works however the query: SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_test' AND `post_id` IN (SELECT post_id FROM `wp_postmeta` where meta_value = 8023) returns the SQL error: Table 'wp_postmeta' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: @MAZux No it wouldn't

Comment: @MAZux see example (I've rewritten the first query in a way that's compatible with MySQL, without changing its meaning). As you can see, the results are different: http://rextester.com/NCL30146